# Laravel 8 - User factory error - `Field 'username' doesn't have a default value`

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-8, factory

I am working on test coverage for this project and now I need to create a User model factory.

I created this factory using the artisan command: `php artisan make:factory UserFactory`

After call `User::factory()->create();` I got next error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `admin_users` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2023-01-01 10:00:00, 2023-01-01 10:00:00))
```

Factory code:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'username' => $this->faker->unique()->userName,
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'avatar' => $this->faker->imageUrl(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail
        ];
    }
}
```

User model code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, HasFactory;

    ...

    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'name',
        'email',
        'avatar'
    ];

    ...
}
```

I tried to set the guarded property as `protected $guarded = []`.

It doesn't help. Other factories in the project work fine

UPD 1: `User::create()` method got the same error. But next code works:

```php
$user = new User();
$user->username = 'Test';
$user->password = Hash::make('test');
$user->name = 'Test';
$user->email = 'test@test.com';
$user->save();
```

UPD 2: User Model's table migrations

```php
//TABLE CREATION

Schema::create(config('admin.database.users_table'), function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username', 190)->unique();
    $table->string('password', 60);
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
    $table->string('remember_token', 100)->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

//Alter table #1

Schema::table(config('admin.database.users_table'), function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('status')->default(0);
    $table->string('email',254)->nullable()->unique();
    $table->timestamp("endOfSubscription")->nullable();
});

//Alter table #2

Schema::table(config('admin.database.users_table'), function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->string('telegramUsername',254)->nullable();
});

//Alter table #3

Schema::table(config('admin.database.users_table'), function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->unsignedInteger('idTelegramUser')->nullable();
});

//Alter table #4

Schema::table(config('admin.database.users_table'), function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->boolean('isBlocked')->default(false);
});

//Alter table #5

Schema::table(config('admin.database.users_table'), function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->boolean("isExtendedRights")->default(false);
});
```

Upd 3: Temporary solution

I added `protected $model = Administrator::class;` to UserFactory and it's helped. But for me, it looks wrong

Comment: As a user mentioned before and I am not sure if you deleted the post or the user deleted the answer, you model is `User` but the SQL is using `admin_users`, so your model and factory should be `AdminUser`, can you give more info please?

Comment: Can we see migration for this table? Are you sure everything fine with this column in db?

Comment: @matiaslauriti in this project used `z-song/laravel-admin` package. And User model extends the Administrator model from this package

Comment: @lezhni Added migrations to description

Comment: @MaxSlyusarchuk could you share the URL to the `admin` model on that package? I am not able to find it

Comment: @matiaslauriti https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin/blob/master/src/Auth/Database/Administrator.php

Answer (score -1):

you can try to specify the model in the UserFactory
`protected $model = admin_users::class;` and don't forget to call the related class model path

Comment: That makes no difference at all

Comment: you can try to specify the model in the UserFactory 
`protected $model = admin_users::class;`
and don't forget to call the related class model path